# Database for .net web api

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for a tip on what database I should use for my api.

The api will be querying one table with maximum of 10 million rows. I'm looking for a free and easy DB which can interact well with c# .net.

Any suggestions?

Comment: .NET can pretty much interact with any database quite easily. When in doubt, use MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your question well, please clarify more.

But for .Net we tend to use SQLServer with .Net Technologies.

For .Net WebAPI2 we used to use SQL Server as Database and Entity-framework code first technology to build our Data layer.

So we build a webAPI

> WebAPI contains Controllers
>
> This controllers get its data from repository pattern classes
>
> Repository pattern classes get it's data from the Entity Framework context
> which it self using the repository patter.

For large data you can use something like DocumentDB, MongoDB (NOSQL technologies)

Comment: Ok, thank u. I will check sql server out